# Behaviour of a function template

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code a function template is used which prints any type of value. This one is using the function templates and not the normal functions

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename any>
void show(any c)
{
    cout<<"Data : "<<c<<endl;
}
main()
{
    int x=99,&r=x;
    int *p=&x;
    show(10);
    show(10.1);
    show("Hello");
    show('@');
    string s("Vector");
    show(s);
    show(r);
    show(p);
}
```

Here First I have passed a character pointer to the function show it works fine but when I pass a integer pointer to it is showing some garbage.

**So when a template can get the value from a `char *` why can't it can get a value from integer pointer**

Output:

```
10
10.1
Hello
@
Vector
99
0xbf839250
```

Comment: Becuase there is a specific overload of `operator<<` taking a `const char*` parameter. It displays the C style string pointed to, not the pointer itself.

Comment: The "garbage" is the pointer value. What did you expect?

Comment: @Baum mit Augen the subject is completely have a look and do not mark genuine questions as duplicate

Comment: @melpomene when a char * is given it prints the corresponding value of it Similarly P is integer pointer So I am expecting the value of X

Comment: @Anjaneyulu If you disagree with my closevote, you can [edit] your question to explain why this is not a duplicate and the community will review my decision.

Comment: Read the dupe; template do not enter into this. The fact that "the template can get the value from a `char *`" is the *exception,* not the rule.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Edited it how can I get it back for the community to answer my question

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the template. You could simply try feeding various things to `std::cout` in `main()` to observe the same results.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu It is put into the reopen review queue automatically and will be reviewed eventually.

Comment: @Quentin ` 
Note that this has nothing to do with the template. You could simply try feeding various things to std::cout in main() to observe the same results`
what does this mean ?

Comment: @Anjaneyulu [See this online snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005cabc2515064b7).

Comment: @Quentin got your idea thanks

Comment: @Anjaneyulu If that were true, it would only print a single `char` when given a `char *`.